# what is the best way to create rest api to accept html template as an input?

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail, fileinputstream

I am using springboot and I need to create Rest APi that will take html template as a parameter. what is the best practice to do that? should I deal with it as @File and save the file in my directory  then send it? because I do not need to save the template I just want to send it as email.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I dealt with it as string and use Template to create new template with src code, however I had to deal with long string now as source code size could matter later.